# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' on line 4 how do i fix

Tags: python

```
print("you have chosen black")
gamble = input("how much do you want to gamble")
print("you have gambled",gamble)
money_left = money_left - gamble
print("you have",money_left,"left")
spin = random.randint(1,20)
print("It landed on....")
time.sleep(3)
print(spin)
```

line 4 not working and money_left already a variable

getting a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: gamble = int(input("how much do you want to gamble"))

Answer (score 1):

Cast gamble to a number

```
money_left = int(money_left) - int(gamble)
```

Comment: The error message says that _both_ arguments are strings.  `money_left` must also be converted to integer.

Comment: Good catch!.. updated accordingly